# Best non-server way to load HTML elements from another file

Tags: html

I'm working on HTML documentation that is meant to be kept in the end user's local file system and like any documentation, a lot of the pages have the same elements, such as a list of navigation links, that I'd like to keep in one location to make them easy to maintain when adding/removing/updating pages.

At present I have a simple jQuery solution that uses the `.load("_link.html")` method, which might be fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this that is more efficient on the end user's computer so the freed up resources could be used for something else: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M9lRPa86TNlGmwz0yFjI?p=preview)

I've tried to use a pure HTML method by using `<iframe>`, but the DOM of the secondary file interferes with that of the primary file (ex. the background behind the elements of "_link.html" in my Plunker would be the background from that file, not from "index.html") and can behave differently in different browsers, so I didn't think this was a good approach.

I've also been exploring something like GruntJS (since it can run on both Linux/OSX and Windows) to build the final HTML on my machine before being delivered to the end user's computer and I like the idea of being able to maintain source files in something like HAML, but there's still a lot I don't know about GruntJS, so I'm unsure if this is the way I want to go about it.

Is there way of doing this that does not depend on the end user's browser to load the jQuery library on every page just to perform simple tasks like this?

Comment: you can use HTML5 `import`: `<link rel="import" href="file.html" />`

Comment: I was reading up on that and saw examples that use either vanilla JS or jQuery to populate the appropriate containers.  Is this more efficient than jQuery's `.load()`?

Comment: you said you wanted something that didn't require jQuery. HTML5 `import` does just that.

Comment: Yes I did.  I also stated that I want the solution to be more efficient than jQuery, hence my follow-up question.  Is that wrong for me to ask?

Comment: well since HTML5 `import` doesn't use jQuery, I would assume it's more efficient because you don't need to use an external library, which in this case would be jQuery

Comment: It does seem like JS or another dynamic language is needed for this to be done at runtime on the end user's computer.  I did find some older static HTML features that might have been able to do what I'm hoping without JS, but what I've been reading about them suggests that they were deprecated in favor of letting JS handle them.  I guess my followup question is more about whether it would be a wasted exercise trying to find a pure and efficient static HTML solution when browsers are being designed and maintained with the expectation that they're going to be using some level of JS anyway.

Comment: Yes, you will be wasting your time trying to find an HTML solution to importing/loading HTML from another file. I personally think `import` is the easiest way.

Comment: This is really only for my own reference, but it's a working example of `import` from multiple template files:
([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EUcQaCL5q4VOEyIIAsKC?p=preview))
([HTML5 Rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/))

Comment: Another working example mainly for my own reference that might be helpful to others.  Since I ran into some cross-browser issues with `import`, I've also been looking at `w3.includeHTML()`.  Though this involves loading the w3.js library, the 20 or so lines of code for this one function could be copied to a separate file that could be loaded instead: ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NCZnleIk6deCha3dv2rL?p=preview)) ([W3 reference](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_references.asp))

Comment: Though it should be noted that some browsers still require a local web server to retrieve locally store files through JS.  Firefox doesn't, but Chrome, MS Edge, and Opera do.  These are what I use for desktop and mobile testing: ([Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)) ([Tiny Web Server Free (Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ar.com.lrusso.tinywebserver.free&hl=en))

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JS to make it work you can do something like this ->
https://jsfiddle.net/4evpde3w/

```
function TemplateAdder(){
// Adds the template to the DOM
this.add = function(append_to, template){
    parent = document.getElementById(append_to)
    parent.innerHTML = template;
}

// Converts the function to a string pulls the template out of it
    this.build = function(template){
      if(typeof template === 'function'){
        return template.toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];
     }
    }

    return this;
}
//  Create a new template Adder
var template_adder = TemplateAdder();

// Have to comment out the temaplate with multi line
// The clousure returns a function that includes the comments

var dropdown_template = (function () {/*

    <div class='dropdown'>
        <h3>
            Dropdown Header
        </h3>
        <p>
            I Am the Dropdown Content
        </p>
    </div>       

*/})

// The build function will convert the returned function into a 
string
// it then parses the string and pulls out the template between the 
comments
var template = template_adder.build(dropdown_template);

// This simple adds our template to the DOM
template_adder.add('dropdown-wrapper', template);
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution that I wanted using `XMLHttpRequest()`.

[W3 Schools' W3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js) library has a complete function `w3.includeHTML()` that checks every element in the DOM for the attribute `w3-include-html` and loads the content of the target URL into the element.

Since I don't have a need for the other functions in that library, I was able to extract the function into my own JS file.  I've checked and it works on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and MS Edge.  The only dependency that I see is on XMLHttpRequest itself, but even then I don't see that changing for the foreseeable future.

As I noted in the comments, some browsers require a basic web server to serve the imported HTML files from the local filesystem through JS (including the other solutions that were discussed) because of security concerns about the file protocol.  The argument could be made that perhaps a little more sophisticated web server that could itself build the complete pages from all of these HTML files could be used instead, but I ultimately decided that a "dumb" localhost would be better for cross-platform support and the client that this is intended for primarily uses Firefox (which does not require a web server) anyway.

I made some minor changes, but this [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/j9uojtxoV7cY55Jeqmx3) is essentially the code extracted from W3.js:

```
// Copied from: https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js

var includeHTML = function() {
  var target_attr = "include-html";
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    file = elmnt.getAttribute(target_attr);
    if (file) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          elmnt.removeAttribute(target_attr);
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
};
includeHTML();
```